# Using caliburn.micro with hierachical viewmodel structure

Tags: c#, mvvm, binding, caliburn.micro

In a project I use `caliburn.micro` as MVVM framework.

Now I have a somewhat big viewmodel for a master-details view.

It is hierarchically built.

Just to have a example:

I have a `ComputerView` with a `ComputerViewModel`. Everything works fine here.

Now this ComputerViewModel contains a `ObservableCollection<HardwareComponentViewModel>`

This `HardwareViewModel` has no `View` attached, it is just there to keep data in place.
Caliburn does not set up `Binding` correctly here. (I cannot use a `x:name` to get a `Binding`)

Until now, that was no problem as I could use the "normal" Binding way.
Now I need to add a `ActionMessage` to a grid in the `HardwareComponentViewModel`.

To make more clear what I mean, here is the full XAML to reproduce it

```
<UserControl x:Class="DemoApplication.Views.ComputersView"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:cal="http://www.caliburnproject.org"
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
             xmlns:i="clr-namespace:System.Windows.Interactivity;assembly=System.Windows.Interactivity"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
             xmlns:s="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib"
             d:DesignHeight="300"
             d:DesignWidth="300"
             mc:Ignorable="d">
    <Grid>
        <Grid.Resources />
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="10*" />
            <RowDefinition Height="2*" />
            <RowDefinition Height="1*" />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="1*" />
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

        <Border HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
                BorderBrush="Transparent"
                BorderThickness="0">
            <ScrollViewer HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch"
                          Background="Yellow"
                          BorderBrush="Transparent"
                          BorderThickness="0"
                          CanContentScroll="True"
                          HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto"
                          VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto">
                <ListView x:Name="Computers"
                          HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch"
                          Background="Red"
                          BorderThickness="0">
                    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <Border Background="Transparent"
                                    BorderBrush="Transparent"
                                    BorderThickness="0">
                                <ListView HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch"
                                          Background="Black"
                                          ItemsSource="{Binding HardwareComponents}">
                                    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                                        <DataTemplate>
                                            <Border Background="Aquamarine"
                                                    BorderBrush="DarkGray"
                                                    BorderThickness="1">
                                                <Grid Background="Lime" cal:Message.Attach="[Event Click] = [Action Expand($dataContext)]">
                                                    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                                        <RowDefinition Height="20" />
                                                    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                                </Grid>
                                            </Border>
                                        </DataTemplate>
                                    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
                                </ListView>
                            </Border>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
                </ListView>
            </ScrollViewer>
        </Border>
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

**Update**

1.
Have tried `cal:Bind.Model="{Binding}"` on the UserControl, but no effect
[Took them from this question here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3650800/bind-a-command-to-a-button-inside-a-listview-with-caliburn-micro?rq=1)

2.
In the Grid I tried:
`cal:Message.Attach="[Event Click] = [Action Expand]"` but did not work either

3.
I added Logging now and get

Action Convention Not Applied: No actionable element for Expand.

But I do not know what it tries to tell me. Perhaps no action can be applied to Grid?

4.
Have now bound it to a button inside the grid, this works.
As a parameter I pass the datacontext, which is indeed the HardwareComponentViewModel,
but it is bubbled to the most outside ViewModel, where the Binding is set up correctly (ComputerViewModel).

```
<Button cal:Message.Attach="[Event Click] = [Action Expand($dataContext)]">
```

**So the question is: What do I have to do to get Binding set up correctly? 
What do I have to do to get ActionMessages in HardwareComponentViewModel called?**

Comment: Can you share the XAML you've tried to use to add an ActionMessage to the Grid?

Comment: @T045T Please have a look at my updated question

Comment: @T045T If this is not enough XAML, please let me know. The View is really big, so I tried to keep the example concise.

Comment: The problem seems to be the grid. And of course that I cannot set up caliburn right for my case...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally made it work!

The event that works is MouseDown, not Click!

```
<Grid cal:Message.Attach="[Event MouseDown] = [Action Expand($dataContext)]" Background="Lime">
```

Thank you all so much for your help!

To be honest, I do not know why it works, but it expands and collapses like a charm :)

Comment: Might be because it's on a Grid and maybe grid doesn't support `Click`# (or something of that nature!) - glad you got it sorted, it's these kind of issues which eat up days on a project :D

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried

`cal:Action.TargetWithoutContext="{Binding DataContext}"`

on your button/grid/wherever you need it? I would expect the target of the action to be the current binding by default, but it may not be (not sure exactly how CM wires it up, might look at the source). Regardless, CM needs to know what target to try to bind the action to (the VM) and due to not being bound the standard CM way my guess is that some wiring can't be done automatically and you need to explicitly bind it using the above code

Comment: Have tried this now for the grid. If I click on it, it gets no longer selected properly, but the Action is not called (at least I do not see it in the Debug output, as I see it for the button that I inserted to try out if any action gets called).

Comment: Probably I'm doing something wrong here. Can you please provide some more information on what I have to do here?

Comment: Will try to make a small example to reproduce the behavior. Probably just a small thing for you, but right now I do not get it to work

Comment: @Carleh: Please have a look at my updated question, have striped down the XAML to the absolute minimum to reproduce it.

Comment: @Carleh it finally works, please have a look at my own answer.

Answer (score 1):

This is more of a comment, really, but I'm putting this into an answer to have proper code formatting. I've used an EventTrigger in a similar situation, and I remember it working flawlessly:

```
<i:Interaction.Triggers>
    <i:EventTrigger EventName="Click">
        <cal:ActionMessage MethodName="Expand" />
    </i:EventTrigger>
</i:Interaction.Triggers>
```

where i is the `System.Windows.Interactivity` namespace, defined in the top-level XAML tag via

```
xmlns:i="clr-namespace:System.Windows.Interactivity;assembly=System.Windows.Interactivity"
```

(Not sure if the exact line should be different for a Desktop app)

Have you tried doing it this way?

Comment: Have inserted this one right after the opening <Grid>. Seems to have no effect, perhaps I have to change some parts. (have changed ContactTapped to Expand as this is the name of the method I want to invoke). Do I have to do something about the "Tap"?

Comment: Sorry about that, the code comes from a mobile application - I'm not sure if "Tap" will work on the desktop as well, so I changed the code snippet to use "Click" - also, since your method doesn't have a parameter, I took that out :)

Comment: Thank you for the update. Right now I get `Action Convention Not Applied: No actionable element for Expand.` at first, but later I get `Action: Expand availability update.` which makes me think that it gets wired correctly. But if I click on the grid, nothing happens, I miss the `Invoking Action: Expand.` part...

Comment: Have you set a background colour for the grid? If the grid is transparent it won't catch clicks...I think you can set a fully transparent colour and it will work similar to transparent (but clickable)

Comment: Yes, I set it to "Lime", but I get no event.

Comment: I'm waiting for my laptop back from the lab today, when I've got it I'll have a quick mess, I'm sure I've done something similar before

Comment: @T045T: Please have a look at my updated question, have striped down the XAML to the absolute minimum to reproduce it.

Comment: @T045T it finally works, please have a look at my own answer.

Comment: Glad you got it to work, and sorry I stopped answering - I was out of ideas, basically ;)