# Extracting data templates in user controls

Tags: c#, wpf, caliburn.micro

There are known problems for setting up caliburn binding in `DataTemplates`.

In [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3651913/863502) EisenbergEffect suggests **extracting Data Templates into a user control**.

**How can this be achieved?**

In my user control I have lots of `DataTemplates` and ran into those problems. `Conventions` are not applied and I have to use "classical" `Binding`.

I could only imagine to extract the whole control with the `DataTemplate`, this would give me lots of smaller controls, but I see no way to only extract the `DataTemplate`.

Here is an example XAML

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.Resources />
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="10*" />
        <RowDefinition Height="2*" />
        <RowDefinition Height="1*" />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="1*" />
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

    <Border HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
            BorderBrush="Transparent"
            BorderThickness="0">
        <ScrollViewer HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch"
                      Background="Yellow"
                      BorderBrush="Transparent"
                      BorderThickness="0"
                      CanContentScroll="True"
                      HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto"
                      VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto">
              <!-- Conventions work here -->
            <ListView x:Name="Computers" 
                      HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch"
                      Background="Red"
                      BorderThickness="0">
                <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <Border Background="Transparent"
                                BorderBrush="Transparent"
                                BorderThickness="0">
                            <ListView HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch"
                                      Background="Black"
                                      ItemsSource="{Binding HardwareComponents}">  <!-- Conventions to not work here -->
                                <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                                    <DataTemplate>
                                        <Border Background="Aquamarine"
                                                BorderBrush="DarkGray"
                                                BorderThickness="1">
                                            <Grid Background="Transparent" cal:Message.Attach="[Event MouseDown] = [Action Expand($dataContext)]" >
                                                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                                    <RowDefinition Height="20" />
                                                </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                                <Border BorderBrush="Red" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch">
                        <!-- Even more DataTemplates come here -->
                                                </Border>
                                            </Grid>
                                        </Border>
                                    </DataTemplate>
                                </ListView.ItemTemplate>
                            </ListView>
                        </Border>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ListView.ItemTemplate>
            </ListView>
        </ScrollViewer>
    </Border>
</Grid>
```

Comment: Have you tried item 3. in Rob's post? *Use the Bind.Model attached property on the root UIElement of the DataTemplate like this Bind.Model="{Binding}". Doing this will cause conventions to be bound against the DataTemplate. Unfortunately, this may not quite work right due to some bugs in Caliburn. It does work in Caliburn.Micro though. I'm hoping to work that bug out soon*. This has the advantage of not requiring explicit bindings, providing that you add the CM attached property correctly

Comment: Have tried it, but did not get it to work

Comment: And the reason for this question is: I'm in fear that I missed a central part of usercontrols

Comment: UserControl is for making a reusable component. Most of the time if a data template is only meant for one area of the application then you don't need a user control (or a separate VM). However, multiple nested templates usually mean that you might be trying to do too much in a single control, consider breaking the control down into smaller viewmodels (all your views are usercontrols anyway right, in which case this should be trivial)

Comment: Yes, I already have them in usercontrols and I already have subviewmodels, which right now do not have views attached. Then having a per control part usercontrol is what Rob Eisenberg meant? Nothing missed about DataTemplates in usercontrols?

Comment: I tend to use a new `UserControl` for each view, unless of course the view is trivial. In this case you can use the `Bind.Model` property - but I'm not sure why it wouldn't work for you. I'll try it myself and put a demo up...

Comment: @Charleh I'm trying to refactor my code and it seems that I did not model it right (ComputerViewModel has an ObservableCollection<HardwareComponentViewModel> which I wanted to factor out first. Have to investigate on that, but cal:Bind.Model seems to be great help). Thank you very much!