# Using Usercontrol inside Datatemplate

Tags: c#, wpf, user-controls, datatemplate, caliburn.micro

On a project I have started using `Caliburn.Micro`.

Now I want to split a large `UserControl` into several smaller `UserControls`, so that I can use them inside of `DataTemplates`. EisenbergEffect suggests to do so [in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3651913/863502)

The `ViewModels` for those are already there, as I modelled the hierachical data as `ObservableCollection<SubViewModel>`.

Now I thought I just have to create the suiting `Views` as `UserControls` for those `SubViewModels`.

My view is a Master-Details view. I want to present a list of Computers and in the Details View I want to have the HardwareComponents of those.

```
<ListView x:Name="ComputerViewModels">
    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <ContentControl x:Name="HardwareComponentViewModel" />
            </DataTemplate>
     </ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>
```

I have included Debug output as suggested here: [Debug Logging](http://buksbaum.us/2010/08/08/how-to-do-logging-with-caliburn-micro/)

And I do not get any output about my HardwareComponentViewModel except 
`Action Convention Not Applied: No actionable element for set_HardwareComponentViewModel`

The HardwareComponentViewModels already get created by the time the ComputerViewModels get created.

I already use the `ContentControl` - way on other parts of the application and it works very well there (getting the `Content` using IOC injected into the outer ViewModel). 
But it does not seem to fit for the DataTemplate part (which is not very surprising, though). The SubViewModels are derived from `Screen`, as the outer ViewModels.

**How can I use the new UserControl as DataTemplate?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a close look at EisenbergEffect's answer. It's explicitly stated, that conventions *don't* work inside `DataTemplate`, so if you have a complicated template, it's better to move it out to a separate `UserControl`, inside which conventions will work again.

That means you have to explicitly bind the model inside the template:

```
<ListView x:Name="ComputerViewModels">
    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <ContentControl cal:View.Model="{Binding HardwareComponentViewModel}" />
            </DataTemplate>
     </ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>
```

That should do it. Either that or `cal:Model.Bind="{...}"`, I can never remember the difference and use case. Now inside the bound `UserControl` (`HardwareComponentView`, I presume) the conventions between view and the view model should work as usual.

Comment: I'm somewhat shocked. Thought I have tried this at least three times. Just inserted `<ContentControl cal:View.Model="{Binding}" />` and now it works! Thank you so much! (by the ways, the not working conventions is the main reason why I want to split the view up)

Comment: @MareInfinitus No problem, glad I could help. Trivial mistakes are often the hardest to catch :)