# Conventions not working inside Hub

Tags: caliburn.micro

I am experimenting the same problem described in https://caliburnmicro.codeplex.com/discussions/539368 , that is if I move a control (e.g. a button) inside a HubSection, in its DataTemplate, the convention does not work anymore.
I read in a post of some years ago ([Bind a Command to a Button inside a ListView with Caliburn.Micro](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3650800/bind-a-command-to-a-button-inside-a-listview-with-caliburn-micro)) that there were problems in "automatically apply conventions to the contents of DataTemplates" and the suggestion was to "1. Do not use conventions inside of DataTemplates; Use explicit bindings and Message. Attach instead".

In fact using the Message.Attach the event is fired to the ModelView ...

So, should I deduce that there is still now the same problem or there is some new work-around?

Thank you
Enzo Contini

Answer (score 1):

Its still a limitation of Caliburn.Micro and XAML Templating interception, therefore the suggestion was either cm:Model.Bind="{Binding}" to the first UIElement of the datatemplate or move it from a datatemplate to a UC or use Explicit bindings cm:Message.Attach etc., nothing has changes as of yet.

Comment: The other two solutions you syggest are not so clear to me: sorry I am new in MVVM and Caliburn!. E.g. in the case of a HubSection thge last solution is  <HubSection x:Uid="HubSection1"><DataTemplate><StackPanelHyperlinkButton micro:Message.Attach="[Event Click] = [Action MyChoice1]" x:Name="MyChoice1" x:Uid="MyHyperLink1"/>  Could you provide an example code to do the same with the solution1 and solution2 you suggested?  Thank you